# Does alternate form affect somatic component?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Hengeyokai are an animal shapeshifting race in Oriental Adventures (p.10).

Invocations are a class feature of the Warlock (Complete Arcane, p.5) and Dragonfire Adept (Dragon Magic, p.25). Complete Arcane (p.7) states that

> all invocations, including *eldritch blast*, have a somatic component.

Can a Hengeyokai in animal form use invocations?

Answer (score 5):

## The Creature Can't Invoke in Animal Form

In the transition from *Dungeons and Dragons, 3rd Edition* to *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*, many creatures--likely including the hengeyokai unless the DM rules otherwise--who previously used an ability like the spell *polymorph self* to assume different forms now use the supernatural ability [alternate form](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#alternateForm).

While in an alternate form

> **The creature** retains any spellcasting ability it had in its original form, although it must be able to speak intelligibly to cast spells with verbal components and it **must have humanlike hands to cast spells with somatic components.**

Emphasis mine. This likely includes warlock and dragonfire adept invocations unless the DM rules otherwise. I ascribe more weight to the creature's inability to employ somatic components than to the *reason* the creature employs somatic components; an alternate reading--like [Mourdos's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/48479/8610)--does the opposite.

However, the only official changes made to the hengeyokai race in its update to *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* in the article "*Oriental Adventures* Update: Eastern Flavor" (*Dragon* #318 32-48) were changing the race's type to *humanoid (shapechanger)* from the type *shapechanger* and removing the hengeyokai's +1 Level Adjustment.

Comment: Devil's advocate: That's talking about "to cast spells", not to invoke.

Comment: @NiteCyper It's talking about somatic components, and, when it was published, nothing but spells had those. One side would then argue that the the *Monster Manual* (2013) (which maintains the original's language) could've but doesn't acknowledge the possibility. The other side would then argue that the core rules don't address *a lot* of things in books outside themselves, and that the DM must use his best judgment in unusual corner cases (such as a creature from *Oriental Adventures* taking levels in a class from *Complete Arcane*). Then they'd draw swords and settle things once and for all.

Answer (score 4):

**As RAW: No.**

From [Alternate Form](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#alternateForm):

> The creature retains any spellcasting ability it had in its original form, although it must be able to speak intelligibly to cast spells with verbal components and **it must have humanlike hands to cast spells with somatic components**.

Note that while this says spellcasting, normal invocations are spell-like abilities that require something spells do (somatic components) and therefore this section is relevant.

**As Opinion:**
Warlocks were never really supported much after they came out. Their invocations are [Spell Like Abilities](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm) but with special mention that they have somatic components. Allowing them to take the Natural Spell feat, or a warlock specific version of it would be up to the DM.

Comment: ...And that's why I like this site.

Comment: Because we agree, or because we got it done so quickly? Took longer in writing mine up :-)

Comment: We disagree on *exactly* the same text for *exactly* different reasons.

Comment: Alternate Form is not Wild Shape (regarding Natural Spell). Nonverbal Spell (Planar Handbook, p. 40) and Surrogate Spellcasting (Savage Species, p. 39) 
are the better choices.

Answer (score 1):

To play devil's advocate, one of the only evidence that I found to support the affirmative is:

> A spellcasting creature that lacks hands or arms can provide any somatic component a spell might require by moving its body.

http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#spells

But it could be argued that that is only supposed to apply to monsters (non-playable characters) and monsters in their natural form at that.

Comment: The alternate form ability's specific rules overrule that.

Comment: "But it could be argued". The rule is generic. If you change your form using an ability, that ability always overrides as it is more specific.